# How to check the length of value in object from arrray of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Using filter()

- Using the athleteData array and .filter():
- return only athlete objects where the athlete's income is more than 7 characters long
- store the returned data in a new `results` variable
  *
- Note:
- do not delete the athleteData variable
- do not alter any of the athleteData content

  ```
  const athleteData = [
   { athlete: 'Lionel Messi', team: 'Barcelona', income: 40000000 },


   { athlete: 'Cristiano Ronaldo', team: 'Juventus', income: 30000000 },


   { athlete: 'Neymar', team: 'Paris Saint-Germain', income: 36800000 },


   { athlete: 'Eden Hazard', team: 'Chelsea', income: 10400000 },


   { athlete: 'Mohamed Salah', team: 'Liverpool', income: 4680000 },


   { athlete: 'Kylian Mbappé', team: 'Paris Saint-Germain: An American Musical', income: 17500000 },

   { athlete: 'Luka Modrić', team: 'Real Madrid', income: 9360000 },

   { athlete: 'Harry Kane', team: 'Tottenham Hotspurs', income: 17600000 },

   { athlete: 'Kevin De Bruyne', team: 'Manchester City', income: 5980000 },

   { athlete: 'Paul Pogba', team: 'Manchester United', income: 15080000 }

  ];

  const results = 'Replace this message with your code!';

  console.log(results);
  ```

  ** The way i am trying to do is**:

const results = athleteData.filter(sorted => sorted.income.length > 7);

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: It looks like an assignment, so this is probably what you are given, but the filtering based on the number of characters in number is weird. For example `1000.00` has 7 characters, but that's probably not something you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just made a `filter` statement according to your rules:

```js
const athleteData = [{
    athlete: 'Lionel Messi',
    team: 'Barcelona',
    income: 40000000
  },

  {
    athlete: 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
    team: 'Juventus',
    income: 30000000
  },

  {
    athlete: 'Neymar',
    team: 'Paris Saint-Germain',
    income: 36800000
  },

  {
    athlete: 'Eden Hazard',
    team: 'Chelsea',
    income: 10400000
  },

  {
    athlete: 'Mohamed Salah',
    team: 'Liverpool',
    income: 4680000
  },

  {
    athlete: 'Kylian Mbappé',
    team: 'Paris Saint-Germain: An American Musical',
    income: 17500000
  },

  {
    athlete: 'Luka Modrić',
    team: 'Real Madrid',
    income: 9360000
  },

  {
    athlete: 'Harry Kane',
    team: 'Tottenham Hotspurs',
    income: 17600000
  },

  {
    athlete: 'Kevin De Bruyne',
    team: 'Manchester City',
    income: 5980000
  },

  {
    athlete: 'Paul Pogba',
    team: 'Manchester United',
    income: 15080000
  }

];

const results = athleteData.filter(({ income }) => income.toString().length > 7);

console.log(results);
```

This filters `athleteData` like so:

First, we destructure (`{ income }`) to get the `income` property of each object as we go through.

Next, we convert it to a string (`.toString()`) so we can check the `length` of each object.

And then we just `console.log(results)` so you can see the data.

Comment: thanks jack the way i am trying to do is,




const results = athleteData.filter(sorted => sorted.income.length > 7);



 
please point out the mistakes and their alternatives.

Comment: You're trying to detect if the length of a number is more than 7 - numbers don't have lengths, which is why I converted to string first.

Comment: You can't do `<Number>.length`, since length is not a property which exists on the prototype, so using `.toString()` is the appropriate way to do this

Comment: @UbaidUllah you might have to do `parseInt(income).toString().length` just in case if any of the income has decimal points.